# Globally disable click out side of ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

ionicModal is appearing like a popup along with backdrop in iPad (Fine in android tabs with full screen view). Modal is closing whenever user clicks on backdrop. It will be an issue if user is filling a form.

Yes, I can use `backdropClickToClose: false` property while creating modal but I used over 60 modals all over my app. Is there any way to set `backdropClickToClose:false` globally in a config like

`$ionicModal.config {
        backdropClickToClose : false
}`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find how to do this using `config`. There currently doesn't seem to be a way to do it that way.

The only thing I found is the [commit](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/910baee2714a55a2cd48af9e54959e92d13d13e9) for the `backdropClickToClose` configuration for `$ionicModal`, which may give others a clue as to how this can be achieved.

Another idea would be to wrap the `$ionicModal` in a service and have some default parameters implemented in there, but I am not sure whether that would be a solution to your problem.

If you really want to be able to configure this, you may want to consider submitting an issue on GitHub, which you can do [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/new).